# Understanding AirCrack output in Backtrack 5

Tags: encryption, kali-linux

First let me clarify that I was trying to crack WPA2 in my home for educational purposes. I followed some tutorials and the message I received was:

> key found! [ilovegod]

I know that this is not my WiFi password. Below that I can see 
the `Master key` and `transient key` and `EAPOL HMAC` but I don't know how to 
translate them.

Is there any way to crack WPA2 using Backtrack 5 or some other way?

Comment: Are your neighbors religious? Maybe you accidentally did their AP instead.

Comment: @scottchamberlain sorry, what is AP?

Comment: AP = Access Point, I was saying "Maybe you accidentally connected to your neighbor's wireless router instead of yours"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Awhitehatter said, brute force is the only way to crack WPA2. It is based on the initial handshake and after that the key can be computed offline. The time necessary to crack WPA2 depends on the complexity of the key and your computational power. There are tools which can help you in cracking a relative weak key (common word(s)) by using so called dictionary lists. If not, you can use [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) to compute all the key combinations.

Just to have an idea about the time it takes to crack a normal WPA2 key (actually a password) using brute force (computing all the combinations), let's pick a decent password containing 8 characters, lower and upper case and digits, with a speed of 600 keys/second on a Quad core, we will crack it in... 36 months! Take into consideration that this is the worse case scenario (100% chances of success). You can calculate other timings based on other given password details using the [Password Calculator](http://lastbit.com/pswcalc.asp).

Also to answer your question, a step by step tutorial on explaining how you can crack WPA2 using Backtrack is available [here](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/02/24/cheatsheet-cracking-wpa2-psk-with-backtrack-4-aircrack-ng-and-john-the-ripper/) and not only...

Answer (score 1):

WPA2 requires a minimum of 8 characters for it's CCMP cipher, which is similar to Rijndael. The only way to get WPA2 passwords is a brute force attack. The attack time will depend of various factors:
Your computational power (clock speed, amount of cores)
Your wordlist length (Usually ranging from Megabytes to Gigabytes)
Your password length (If you are cracking a foreign AP, you should not know this length.)
Common words in password.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly got the `WEP` or `WPA` password of one of your neighbor wireless
network (as guessed [Scott](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/2221/scott-chamberlain)).

Since this is illegal, and may compromise you,
you should locate this neighbor (this is another
interesting security topic per se), and inform him.

You will have to inform your neighbour that you accidentaly got
his network password, that the technic he is using to secure his network
is false security (as usefull as an empty extinguisher). That his technic `WEP` or `WPA` is easily broken by any neighbor within seconds. Then his
computer and his network traffic are completely stripped bare.

To stay accidentaly the owner of your neighbor wireless password may compromise you in the same way than keeping the keys of his appartment
may compromise you. Let's imagine for a while that this neighbor is a criminal torturing children in his
appartement and broadcasting snuff movies on the Internet. To exhibit
that you have an access to the network of this neighbor may let him defend
on the ground that his network was hacked:

"See, this is not coming from me. My network is hacked and used by this neighbor. All his traffic is coming from my IP address. He did it to hide behind my network access. This is clearly your guy."

The only real security on wireless networks has a completely different kind of name. It's `802.11i`. All the other commercial names starting with `Wi-Fi` are just empty extinguishers.